# Why react and css mediaqueries not working together?

Tags: css, reactjs

A really courious thing:
i bought a template, use it for ever 2 years without problems and now i want to play with react and even this template and now the mobile view (especially the media queries) are completely ignored.
`i have read about this but there are many ideas to put the queries to the end of file - but thats not the problem here`

i can see during the rendering that the mediaqueries extrem short works, but when react is mount there is nothing to see from my media queries. Simply away.
The next thing is, that the bootstrap class `d-md-none` not works in react, only in pure html. i used exactly the same files during webpack.

Can anyone tell me why , and how i can solve this?

as an example:

```
<div className="logo-container">
  <Link className="logo m-0" to={"/app"} >
    <img src="../../images/logo_light.png" alt="alt" style={{width:120}} />
  </Link>
  <div className="d-md-none toggle-sidebar-left" data-toggle-class="sidebar-left-opened" data-target="html" data-fire-event="sidebar-left-opened">
    <i className="fas fa-bars" aria-label="Toggle sidebar"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

The example above has the following css rule in pure html:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .header .logo-container {
    height: 60px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99;
  }
```

this works perfect, until i take react now. In react there are no css rules set. All mediaqueries (2000 lines) are ignored.
(btw. problems are in chrome, safari and edge browsers)
Many Thanx to every idea you have.